# Split String in get set function

Tags: c#, string, get, split, set

I am trying to find a way to automatically split my incoming string into a nicely parsed array or list. I have a `<textarea>` on my page that will either do comma or space delimiting. That `<textarea> will be filling my`multiChoiceOptions`. Then i want my get/set to automatically parse it the string into a string array.

Am i on the right track?

```
        private string _options;
        public string[] multiChoiceOptions
        {
            get {
                this._options = splitString(this._options);
                return this._options; 
            }

            set { 
                this._options = value; 
            }
        }

        public string[] splitString(string value)
        {
            string[] lines = Regex.Split(value, "\r\n");

            return lines;
        }
```

Comment: `Am i on the right track?` I don't know. First post a compilable code.

Comment: Why do you need two method just to split string and stock in string variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a pair of properties, one for the original option list and the other for the parsed array.  The parsing would be done on the setter of the original optional value.

Since the proper way to set the options is using the source options string the parsed array does not need a setter.

```
   private string[] z_multiChoiceOptions = null;
    public string[] multiChoiceOptions
    {
        get
        {
            return this.z_multiChoiceOptions;
        }

    }

    private string z_Options = null;
    public string Options
    {
        get { return z_Options; }
        set { 
            z_Options = value;
            if (value != null)
                this.z_multiChoiceOptions = Regex.Split(value, "\r\n");
            else
                this.z_multiChoiceOptions = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting all array variable all at onces in string variable is impossible in your code.

For example: The correct way to store array in your code is.

```
private string _options;
private string[] newArray; //declare new array for storing array.
    public string[] multiChoiceOptions
    {
        get {
            this.newArray= splitString(this._options);
            return this.newArray; 
        }

        set { 
            this.newArray = value; 
        }
    }

    public string[] splitString(string value)
    {
        string[] lines = value.split(","); //use String.Split

        return lines;
    }
```

I use your code in Console Application.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] arrayEmpty = new string[]{}; //I use empty array cause I don't know what you want to do.
        multiChoiceOptions = arrayEmpty;
    }

    private static string _options = "samle,sample";
    private static string[] newArray;
    public static string[] multiChoiceOptions
    {
        get
        {
            newArray = splitString(_options);
            return newArray;
        }

        set
        {
            newArray = value;
        }
    }

    public static string[] splitString(string value)
    {
        string[] lines = value.Split(','); //use String.Split

        return lines;
    }
```